# Is it possible to continue playing music even system gets locked for inactivity?

Tags: release-freya, greeter, music

I am using elementary OS freya *0.3.2*.

As the title says, Is it possible to continue playing music even system gets locked for inactivity? In Ubuntu, system continue to play music after it was locked. But in elementary its not working (atleast for me).

Is there any way to make the system continue to play music even it is suspended for inactivity.

Comment: I don't think so. There's a bug over there in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/noise/+bug/1468543

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was adding my user into the 'audio' group.  This isn't necessarily a good idea for the reasons listed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup?highlight=%28audio%29), but for a single user system shouldn't be problematic.

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio myusername
```